# WordPress few posts are not showing in dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm using [AIT Theme](http://www.ait-themes.com/) for my WordPress site. And the issue is some of posts I published is not showing in the dashboard but the count is there. And its also not showing in the website.

[image]

Comment: Is there any plugin like adblock is there? if its yes then it might be blocking post from listing

Comment: No plugins like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your Total post 25 and `Publish` 5, Wordpress post working 2 status. 
    1) `Draft` 
    2) `Pubilsh`
    Your another 20 post is in `draft` status below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the **status** of your posts to **published** !  As in the image below you can see the posts which are published can only be seen ! 
[image]

Comment: I'm not even able to see the other 20 posts. Then how i can change the status ?

Comment: they must have been in **trash** !

Comment: Its not even in Trash. But i found everything in my database.